# Help with capturing URL fragment in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I am working on a django project, and trying to match URLs in the following form:

/cards/series/SERIES NAME/

where I am trying to capture SERIES NAME

My base urls.py includes:

```
(r'^cards/', include('cards.urls')),
```

and then my cards/urls.py includes

```
(r'^series/(\w+)/$',
```

However, the regex is not matching (404). If I hard code the path like so:

```
(r'^series/foo/$',
```

Then I can get it to match on /cards/series/foo/

So, does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong, and why my regex isnt catching /cards/series/SERIES NAME/ ?

Update : The regex will match single words, but not multiple. So:

```
/cards/series/FOO/
```

matches, but:

```
/cards/series/FOO BAR/
```

or anything with a space does not match.

Update : Found the solution here:

[how to unescape special characters in django urlpatterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275203/how-to-unescape-special-characters-in-django-urlpatterns)

which is:

```
(r'^series/([\w ]+)/$',
```

Comment: Can you tell us, which url exactly you tried to match with `r'^series/(\w+)/$'`?

Comment: Yes, I just realized it will match single words, but not multiple. I have updated the original with more info.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to have spaces in URLs.  They must be escaped.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding

So essentially, don't do this.  If spaces are important they should wind up in your URL as things like `/cards/series/SERIES%20NAME/`.  It is considered better practice to use hyphens these days, although underscores are okay too.  Use of capital letters is legal, but will strike some people (like me) as poor form.

As for why the pattern doesn't work, Django query patterns are regular expressions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

You are capturing the pattern `\w+`.  And `\w` is a stand-in for `Alphanumeric characters plus "_"`, while the ensuing `+` says to match `one or more of the preceding element`.  Whitespace is not an alphanumeric character, so if you wanted to match spaces as well you'd have to add it to a set as you have found.  Brackets are used to indicate a set of acceptable characters, so `[\w ]+` would mean `Alphanumeric characters plus "_" plus " "`

Again, don't do it.